# Find all integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that all roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+10$ are integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find all integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that all roots of $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+10$ are integers.

Let the roots of $f$ are $p,q,r$.
Then, by Vietta, $p+q+r=-a, pq+pr+qr=b$, and $pqr=-10$. It means that all roots of $f$ are the multiple of the factor of $10$.

Whats next? What if $c$ in $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is a big number, for example $200$?

Comment: In how many ways can you write $-10$ as the product of three integers? There are not so many.

Comment: What if its changed by 210? Does it similar?

Comment: @WhatsUp $210=(2)(3)(5)(7)$, but there are only three roots of $f$. What about it?

Comment: " 210=(2)(3)(5)(7), but there are only three roots of f. What about it?"  well, *what* about it.  you'd try all combinations.  (I think there are 45).  Why would you thiink the answer to *all* possibilities would have small numbers of answers.  The more factors the last term has the more answers there will be.

Comment: The problem might be more interesting if it were “count the number of integer pairs $(a,b)$ such that all roots are integer.”

Comment: And besides of that, what if the function $f(x)$ has only one integer root?

Answer (score 1):

From the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) every rational root of every monic polynomial with integer coefficients must be integer.

So with that in mind we can say that since *a* and *b* are integers the roots *p*, *q* and *r* also integers.

And as you already stated *pqr* = -10

I believe the corresponding integer values would be (-2,5,1), (2,-5,1), (2,5,-1), (-2,-5,-1) and (10,-1,1), (10,1,-1)

This gives you 6 values of *(a,b)*

Comment: Gotcha! But, what about the case $pqr=-210$?

Comment: What about, for example, $(-2,-5,-1)$? Since $(-2)(-5)(-1) = -10$.

Comment: Do you want to find the solution for that particular number or are you asking how to find the roots if the *c* values is large ?

Comment: For the large $c$ I think.

Comment: @user795084 Thank you for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: For large c one could just use a computer, if you are asking this from an exam point of view I do not think they will ask large values for c

Comment: Hmm, okay nevermind. Anw, thanks!